# Ubuntu не запускается

Tags: ubuntu

В процессе работы Убунту поймала ошибку и даже переустановка не решила проблему. При загрузке чёрный экран и сообщение. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нажмите комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+Alt+F2 (если ничего, то Ctrl+Alt+F3 попробуйте) и отпишитесь о результате.

Comment: Ничего не происходит при нажатии. Когда система подвисала при жизни, эта комбинация помогала или выйти из подвисания или корректно перезагрузку сделать.

Comment: Тогда без понятия. Если у вас ноутбук, то попробуйте отключить все usb устройства.

Comment: Там чё-то про uefi написано. В настройках бука ковырялся?

Comment: Уже много всего перековырял, даже вчера переустановку выполнил - результат тот же. Может быть есть смысл в сервисный центр обратиться...